# Классы и наследование,

Tags: python, классы, наследование, python-3.6

**выдает ошибку `Failed test - test_5[carrying-Nissan-f1.jpg-1-5]. E   AssertionError: Тест 5.2. Атрибут carrying экземпляра класса Car должен возвращать объект типа: float. assert False +  where False = isinstance('1', <class 'float'>) +    where '1' = getattr(<solution.Car object at 0x7fc3f5b5f0f0>, 'carrying')`**

```
import csv
import os.path

TYPE_CAR = 'car'
TYPE_TRUCK = 'truck'
TYPE_SPEC_MACHINE = 'spec_machine'

class CarBase:
    def __init__(self, car_type, brand, photo_file_name, carrying):
        self.car_type = car_type
        self.photo_file_name = photo_file_name
        self.brand = brand
        self.carrying = carrying
        
    def set_photo_file_name(self, filename):
        self.photo_file_name = filename
    def set_brand(self, brand):
        self.brand = brand
    def set_carrying(self, carrying):
        self.carrying = float(carrying)
       
    def get_photo_file_ext(self):
        return os.path.splitext(self.photo_file_name)[1]

class Car(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, passenger_seats_count):
        super().__init__(TYPE_CAR, brand, photo_file_name, carrying)

        self.passenger_seats_count = passenger_seats_count

    def set_passenger_seats_count(self, count):
        self.passenger_seats_count = int(count)

class Truck(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, passenger_seats_count):
        super().__init__(TYPE_CAR, brand, photo_file_name, carrying)

        self.passenger_seats_count = passenger_seats_count

    def set_body_width(self, width):
        self.body_width = float(width)
    def set_body_height(self, height):
        self.body_height = float(height)
    def set_body_length(self, length):
        self.body_length = float(length)
        
    def get_body_volume(self):
        return self.body_width * self.body_height * self.body_length
        
class SpecMachine(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, passenger_seats_count):
        super().__init__(TYPE_CAR, brand, photo_file_name, carrying)

        self.passenger_seats_count = passenger_seats_count
        
    def set_extra(self, extra):
        self.extra = extra

def parse_row(row):
    brand = row[1]
    photo_file_name = row[3]
    carrying = row[5]
    if row[0] == TYPE_CAR:
        car = Car(brand, photo_file_name, carrying, row[2])
        
def get_car_list(filename):
    cars = list()
    with open(filename) as csv_fd:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_fd, delimiter=';')
        next(reader) # skip csv header
        for row in reader:
            car = parse_row(row)
            if car is not None:
                cars.append(car)

    return cars
```

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, проблема в том, о чем говорит ошибка. В конструкторе `Car` (метод `__init__`) у вас есть только один (неявный) параметр - `self`, а в `test_4` вы передаете еще 4 дополнительных параметра (в придачу к неявному `self`), итого 5, а допустим только 1.

Если вы хотите создавать объекты и инициализировать их в конструкторе (и это правильное желание, лучше чем сейчас), то вам нужно добавить дополнительные параметры в классы `CarBase` и `Car`:

```
class CarBase:
    def __init__(self, car_type, brand, photo_file_name, carrying):
        self.car_type = car_type
        self.photo_file_name = photo_file_name
        self.brand = brand
        self.carrying = carrying

class Car(CarBase):
        def __init__(self, brand, , photo_file_name, carrying, passenger_seats_count):
        super().__init__(TYPE_CAR, brand, photo_file_name, carrying)
        self.passenger_seats_count = passenger_seats_count
```

Аналогично нужно сделать и для других наследников. Ну и потом в парсере использовать эти конструкторы:

```
    brand = row[1]
    photo_file_name = row[3]
    carrying = row[5]
    if row[0] == TYPE_CAR:
        car = Car(brand, photo_file_name, carrying, row[2])
```